# Schema reference failed to read schema

Tags: spring

I'm using spring 3.2.5 on my project. So when I create my appliation-context.xml I have this warning:

```
schema_reference.4: failed to read schema document http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd because :
1)could not find the document
2)the document could not be read
3)the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>
```

I don't know where the problem is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just could remove this warning by changing this on my applicationContext.xml :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
  ">
```

by

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd 
">
```

because (from what I read) when using the first we try to load the latest version that is released and that could not be supported by the version that we actually use or does not exists !!

Comment: I faced this problem in 2 machines and one machine took the xml with out mentioning any version and the other machine, warning gone when I mentioned the version. So try the 2 cases mentioned here and see which one resolved the issue to you.

Comment: That what i have done too . I relized the same thing some times it's the first solution witch works somtimes the second one. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

xsi:schemaLocation ="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-context.xsd"

You just remove save once and again paste it. Then error is gone.

Comment: This is exactly what the answer by Chamila Maddumage mentioned. Please don't add the same answer again.

Comment: I did not added the same answer. He told remove those lines. That's not working. You need to paste again. Then only error will gone. That is workspace error.

Answer (score 0):

I removed these lines and errors were solved.

```
xsi:schemaLocation ="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-context.xsd"
```

Comment: There was a missing " in my answer. Answer has been edited and you can try it again.